# Magento 2: setCustomPrice vs. setOriginalCustomPrice

Tags: magento2, price

I have seen several examples showing how to adjust prices in carts. I do not understand the difference between setCustomPrice and setOriginalCustomPrice. Where is CustomPrice and OriginalCustomPrice used later on?

```
class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {


        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()+60; 
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any update if my explenation works for you?

Answer (score 6):

> - custom_price : new price that can be declared by user and recalculated during calculation process.
> - original_custom_price : original defined value of custom price without any convertion.

**It will be safe to set both.**

[This link can be useful.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/c077da60335dfeb72d9678d519e38d4191170dd9/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/AbstractItem.php#L15-L16)

Comment: This is what the core code says, but it's not 100% accurate. If you set custom_price & original_custom_price that way, this bug comes up: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33134

Comment: BTW, I just created a patch to fix the known-issue that I described previously: https://github.com/araujophillips/magento2-issue-33134/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

Both the SetCustomPrice and SetOriginalCustomPrice seems to be a part of the Quote Update system.

First lets understand the difference between 
->setPrice()
->setOriginalPrice()

> - - price - initial item price, declared during product association
> - - original_price - product price before any calculations

Now the difference between setPrice and SetCustomPrice you already know i think. A price is the price of the product in your product stock. Custom Price is the price that you give it on your order.

So SetCustomPrice  is the price you give it in your invoice and SetCustomOriginalPrice is the Product Price that you give it but before any calculations (before any discounts etc)