# Magento 2 - Change Product Price if Custom Value is Selected

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, cart, custom-options

I am using Magento 2.3.6

I have on the Product Page an Custom HTML Select Field: Yes / No

I want the price to Change if selected Field is set to "Yes" and keep the same price if it is set to "No".

At the moment i got this Product.php Class

```
namespace Vendor\Name\Model;

class Product
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function afterGetFinalPrice($product, $proceed) : float
    {
        return $proceed+10;
    }
}
```

What i want is to set $proceed + 10 only if the Custom Produt Attribute is set to "Yes".

Under Vendor_Module/etc i have di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="change_product" type="Vendor\Name\Model\Product" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Any Ideas?

How can i get .phtml Value from Frontend into PHP File before adding to Shooping Cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for my question.

Based on Renon Stewart Answer:

[How to "add to cart" a product with custom input field and save it to Database?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132009/how-to-add-to-cart-a-product-with-custom-input-field-and-save-it-to-database)

In the addtocart.phtml view i created this block:

```
<select name="cloudways[isConfigured]" id="selectBlock">
        <option value="no">No</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

In the above example the passed attribute value would be the selected option of "isConfigured".

Than in The CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver Class i check for the attribute.

I created for it this function and check if the "key" equals "isConfigured" attribute value.

```
protected function isProductConfigured($post) {
    $isProductConfigured = '';
    if(is_array($post)){
        foreach($post as $key => $value){

            if($key == 'isConfigured'){
                    $isProductConfigured = $value;
            }
        }
    }
  return $isProductConfigured;
}
```

I call this function in the exectue(EventObserver $observer) function
after

```
$post = $this->_request->getParam('cloudways');

if($this->isProductConfigured($post) == "yes") {

}
```

After that based on this answer:

[Magento 2: setCustomPrice vs. setOriginalCustomPrice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199143/magento-2-setcustomprice-vs-setoriginalcustomprice)

I can update my Cart Price:

```
$price = $item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()+10; 
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a new attribute with yes and no value and set for product using product attribute and set yes value + 10.